# Converting VBScript's Imp Operator

Tags: powershell, vbscript

If you google for [PowerShell Imp](https://www.google.nl/search?q=PowerShell%20Imp) you currently will find the [VBScript-to-Windows PowerShell Conversion Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee176871.aspx) on top of the list. Yet the answer is much of technical help:

## *Imp Operator*

***Definition:*** Performs a logical implication on two expressions.

*What do we know about the Imp operator? Two things: 1) it’s not supported in Visual Basic .NET, and 2) we have never heard of anyone actually using it. Therefore, we’re going to say that it doesn’t really matter whether or not there’s a Windows PowerShell equivalent.*

In fact, I used the `Imp` operator (also written as: `A→B`) a  number of times in VBScript and likely would have used it in PowerShell if it existed.

## Example 1

I want to copy any file that is not hidden except if it is set to be archived (it also needs to be copied).
A command for this would have been something like:

```
If (($File.Attributes -match "Hidden") -imp ($File.Attributes -match "Archive")) {Copy $File}
```

## Example 2

I have a `Log-Entry` cmdlet with a `Log-Debug` alias. Similar to the native `Write-Host`/`Write-Debug` functions; when the `Log-Debug` *alias* is used, the information not be revealed but only be recorded when the common `-Debug` is supplied.
A command for this would have been something like:

```
If (($Noun -eq "Debug") -imp $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.Debug.IsPresent) {Add-content $LogFile $$Entry}
```

How can I build a logical implication operator with a minimum of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take the definition quiet literally, you will probably come to a statement like for a logical implication:

```
If ($Expression1) {If ($Expression2) {DoThis}} Else {DoThis}
```

Which might get quiet excessive as you need to execute twice the same function.
So, it is preferable to have a single If condition as replacement for the VBScript's `Imp` operator which made me come up with:

```
If (($True, [Bool]$Expression2)[[Bool]$Expression1]) {...}
```

But a little further investigation led me even to a much simpler replacement for the VBScript's Imp operator:

---

```
If (!$Expression1 -or $Expression2) {...}
```

---

## Check

```
0..3 | ForEach {
    $Expression1, $Expression2 = [Int]($_ / 2), [Int]($_ % 2)
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Expression1 = [Bool]$Expression1
        Expression2 = [Bool]$Expression2
        Implication = !$Expression1 -or $Expression2
    }
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

## Truth Table

```
Expression1 Expression2 Implication
----------- ----------- -----------
      False       False        True
      False        True        True
       True       False       False
       True        True        True
```

**Note:** In this solution `$Null` expressions are considered `$False`. This differs from the VBScript `Imp` implementation but is consistent with other PowerShell operators that contain `$Null` expressions. e.g. The VBScript statement: `If 1 And vbNull Then msgbox "True" Else msgbox "False"`, returns `True` where the PowerShell statement `If (1 -And $Null) {"True"} Else {"False"}`, returns `False`.

## Bitwise

If you looking for a bitwise `Imp` operator (which should probably be called -`bImp`, if it existed), then it would be:

```
$Implication = -bNot Expression1 -bOr Expression2    # e.g.: -bNot 3 -bOr 5 = -3 (-bAnd 0xF = 13)
```